# How to logout on 401 using a fetch client for data queries?

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest, fetch

In a web application, I am reusing my `dataProvider` specified on `react-admin` website : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#data-providers in another react application.

They are able to disconnect and redirect to login if any request return a `401` response.

In my other react app which is not react admin, I am not having this redirection when my request fail (session timeout).

This is how look my `dataProvider`:

```
const dataProvider = {
    getList:    (resource, params) => Promise,
    getOne:     (resource, params) => Promise,
    getMany:    (resource, params) => Promise,
    getManyReference: (resource, params) => Promise,
    create:     (resource, params) => Promise,
    update:     (resource, params) => Promise,
    updateMany: (resource, params) => Promise,
    delete:     (resource, params) => Promise,
    deleteMany: (resource, params) => Promise,
}
```

I have checked in the code and I was expecting to see a wrapper for each of these methods, that would add the `catch` and trigger the redirect to login when necessary.

Instead, I am not seing that, and I'd like to know why and how I should solve this matter properly in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say alot without any other code. Need something more so we can reproduce. Does `Promise` is directly a reference to Promise library you're using? Specific answer depends entirely on architecture and other supporting library you have.

These are the steps we have with `redux`, `react-router-dom`

1. Authentication/Data request fails
2. Destroy localstore credentials.
3. Trigger a side-effect / App state change through `LogoutAction`
4. Update redux store with app state.
5. Higher Order Component `PrivateRoute` wraps all the routes that need to be private. It checks the `isLoggedIn` state and returns Page Component or redirect user to `/login`

e.g.

```
// handle promise error
    private handleError = (errorMessage: Error) => {
        const message = JSON.parse(errorMessage.message);
        if (message.status === 401) {

            this.authentication.logout(); // triggers logout actions and destroy credentials
        }
        throw errorMessage;
    }
```

```
    private destroyUserCredentials() {
        this.tokenResponse = null;
        this.tokenClaims = null;
        this.tokenHasExpired = true;
        this.accessToken = null;
        this.localStorage.removeItem(this.storageKey);
    }
```

```
 // dispatch action to change redux store state
 appStore.dispatch(LogOutAction());
```

```
// Private route HOC
export const PrivateRouteComponent = ({ component: Component, state: state, ...rest }) => {
    const renderComponent = (props) => {
        if (state.login.isLoggedIn) {
            return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
            return <Redirect to='/login' />;
        }
    };

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={renderComponent}
      />
    );
  };

// REF: pluralsight connect container
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        state: {
            login: state.authenticate
        }
    };
}

export const PrivateRoute = connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRouteComponent);
```

```
// Route setup
 <Provider store={appStore}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
                    <PrivateRoute path='/analytics' component={HomePage} />
                    <PrivateRoute path='/account' component={AccountPage} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
```

Comment: Why do you need to replace `<Route />`, why not just create a component below with the security ?

Comment: What do you mean by `component below with the security` ? We are not really replacing the `Route`. `PrivateRoute` is just a wrapper around `Route`. It takes the component you want to render as property. Then inside the `PrivateRoute` component you check authenticated state then return either `Route` with the `PageComponent` or `Redirect`

Comment: Ok, I understand totally, but I want to know why do you need to replace `<Route />` with `<PrivateRoute />` specifically. If the usual is `Route > View`, why not just `Route > Security > View`, this seems to be as efficient and does not require to touch react router route component behavior.

Comment: There is no change to how `Route` behaves. If you look at the code you will see it's always returning `Route`. Difference is the component that's passed to Route. Think of it bit like a `closure` you could move the `isLoggedIn` state logic to `HomePage` and then duplicate again for `AccountPage` but then you're just repeating it every component.

Comment: You missunderstood the question, I understand the logic behind `<PrivateRoute />` and I understand that it will work. Now moving forward to my next remark, I was not talking about moving the logic of `isLoggedIn` into every route, but using a child component to `<Route />` different than the `<HomePage />` and `<AccountPage />` but a parent used for every private route. I want to know the tradeoff between the `<PrivateRoute />` solution and `<Route path="/account" component={(routeProps) => <Secured {...routeProps}><AccountPage {...routeProps} /></Secured>}/>` way of solving the security

Comment: I think we can avoid the talk to explain how the `<PrivateRoute />` work because this is already assimilated.  What I'd like you to focus on is my solution that include a specific component for solving the secure `<Route />` problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212960/discussion-between-montecristo-and-dimitri-kopriwa).

Comment: By secure route, I mean private route. It's the same thing, this is the terminology I use:
- Route : a react-router route
- PrivateRoute : MonteCristo implementation of secure route, which involve wrapping the Route and add the logic to check if user is authed
- SecureRoute: random implementation for checking authentication on a route
My question is, why do you replace the Route and what is the benefits of replacing the Route? We could use a child component instead,

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa let us continue in the chat please. I am happy to clarify things as much as possible.